# Why is ngModel.$setViewValue(...) not working from

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm writing an directive which needs an isolated scope, but I want to bind it to the parent scope via [ngModel](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController).

Here the problem is that the parent's scope value is not getting changed.

Markup

```
<form name="myForm" ng-app="customControl">
    <div ng-init="form.userContent"></div>
    <div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="form.userContent" required>Change me!</div>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <hr />
    <textarea ng-model="form.userContent"></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
angular.module('customControl', []).directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        require : '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
        scope: {},
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel)
                return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            // Specify how UI should be updated
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
            };

            // Listen for change events to enable binding
            element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                        scope.$apply(read);
                    });
            read(); // initialize

            // Write data to the model
            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hwv7E/4/).

This works fine if I don't use a isolated scope for the directive

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hwv7E/3/).

Comment: Shouldn't `element.html(ngModel.$viewValue...)be `element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue)..)` I know this is almost exactly the same as in the ng docs example, but I've just discovered this effectively bypasses xss protection otherwise.

Comment: @arun Can you explain why the isolate scope make it not working?

Comment: Re @cirrus comment, it seems to me that to avoid XSS, that whenever anything is placed into the element it should first be sanitized with $sanitize (i.e. do not trust the HTML). Something like element.html($sanitize(ngModel.$viewValue))`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The reason is that since you're creating an isolated scope for your `contenteditable` directive, the `ng-model` directive on the same element gets that isolated scope as well. Which means that you have two different scopes that aren't connected to each other, which both have a `form.userContent` property that changes separately. I guess you could exemplify it by this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    })
    .directive('contenteditable', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'A', // only activate on element attribute
            require : '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
            scope: {},
            link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel)
                    return; // do nothing if no ng-model

                setInterval(function() {
                    if (angular.element('#contenteditable').scope().form)
                        console.log(angular.element('#contenteditable').scope().form.userContent);

                    if (angular.element('#textarea').scope().form)
                        console.log(angular.element('#textarea').scope().form.userContent);
                }, 1000);

                // Specify how UI should be updated
                ngModel.$render = function() {
                    element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
                };

                // Listen for change events to enable binding
                element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                            scope.$apply(read);
                        });
                read(); // initialize

                // Write data to the model
                function read() {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
                }
            }
        };
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div ng-init="form.userContent"></div>
        <div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="form.userContent" id="contenteditable" required>Change me!</div>
        <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
        <hr />
        <textarea ng-model="form.userContent" id="textarea"></textarea>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

As you'll see in your console, there are two different scopes and `form.userContent` on them change separately if you change the text in the textarea or if you change the text in your contenteditable div.

So I bet you're thinking "enough with the explaining and show me a solution!". Well, there aren't (to my knowledge) a pretty solution for this, but there is one that works. What you want to do is bring a reference of the model into your isolated scope, and make sure that it has the same name in your isolated scope as in the parent scope.

Here's what you do, instead of creating an empty scope like this:

```
...
scope: {}
...
```

You bind the model like this:

```
...
scope: {
    model: '=ngModel'
}
....
```

Now you have a `model` property on your isolated scope that is a reference to `form.userContent` on your parent scope. But `ng-model` isn't looking for a `model` property, it's looking for a `form.userProperty` which still doesn't exist in our isolated scope. So to fix this, we add this inside our linking function:

```
scope.$watch('model', function() {
    scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel + ' = model');
});

scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(val) {
    scope.model = val;
});
```

The first watch syncs changes on `form.userContent` that comes from outside of our directive to our isolated `form.userContent`, and the second watch makes sure that we propagate any changes on our isolated `form.userContent` up to the parent scope.

I realize that this is a lengthy answer, and perhaps not very easy to follow. So I'd be happy to clearify anything that you feel is blurry.

Comment: When you say "[...] the ng-model directive on the same element gets that isolated scope as well. Which means that you have two different scopes that aren't connected to each other", if the same isolated scope is shared by both `ng-model` and `contenteditable`, how come then you say they have two different scopes? It looks like a contradiction. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @anders I am not clear how the isolate scope break the code. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @ Anders Ekdahl  If multiple directives on an element provide an isolate scope, only one new scope is applied.(reference Ng-Book ,page 111 ,Scope Option Heading)

Answer (score 4):

the first answer explains the problem well, I believe i have a simpler solution that avoids extra watches.

to summarize answer 1. ngModel can not work inside the isolate scope because the elements you intended it to bind to are not in its scope. they are in the parent scope.

solution 1, bind to the parent's property

```
<div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="form.userContent" required>Change me!</div>
```

becomes

```
<div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="$parent.form.userContent" required>Change me!</div>
```

solution 2, move ngModel outside the isolate scope

`require : '?ngModel',` becomes `require : '?^ngModel',` the ^ tells your directive to look in parent elements for ngModel

```
<div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="form.userContent" required>Change me!</div>
```

becomes

```
<div ng-model="form.userContent">
    <div contenteditable name="myWidget" required>Change me!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found this answer to be to the point and most helpful. You might want to complete the answer with the dual-$watch approach as it is a legitimate (and widely applied) solution.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will work for you. However you can give it a try.

html:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-app="customControl">
    <div ng-init="form.userContent"></div>
    <div contenteditable name="myWidget" ng-model="form" required>Change me!</div>
    <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
    <hr />
    <textarea ng-model="form.content"></textarea>
</form>
```

js

```
angular.module('customControl', []).directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A', // only activate on element attribute
        require : '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel)
                return; // do nothing if no ng-model
            // Specify how UI should be updated
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
            };

            // Listen for change events to enable binding
            element.bind('blur keyup change', function() {
                        scope.$apply(read);
                    });
            read(); // initialize

            // Write data to the model
            function read() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue({'content': element.html()});
            }
        }
    };
});
```